# Can more than one High Volume Community User have the ability the see the same case in the Customer Commnunity

Tags: community, case, customer-community, licenses

I have a requirement to allow more than one High Volume Customer Community user to see a single case in the Customer Community.

I have created a sharing set, however the sharing set only allows a single option. If there is more than one linked to the case I can only configure the sharing set to allow one external user to see it.

Is the only answer to have Customer Community Plus Licenses or is there a programatic solution to this, as yet I am struggling to find a configurable solution

Any help is greatly appreciatd